# How do I concat a string and an int and find its value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, push, concatenation

***See the final codebase below. My initial approach of trying to use an array as an object was incorrect.***

I'm trying to concat a string and int to look up a particular item in an array `arr`. The current code base console logs `undefined`.

Can someone explain why `undefined` is console logged?

**Codebase in question:**

```
const a = "T";
const b = 2;
const c = a + b;

let arr = [
        T0: 0,
        T1: 1,
        T2: 1
    ];

console.log(arr.find(e => e == c));
```

**Thank you.**

*More detail (not necessary to read):*

I'm trying to write code to provide an answer for an n-th Tribonacci number when inputted `n`.

**Psuedo-code:**

```
var tribonacci = function(n) {
  
    let arr = [
        T0 = 0;
        T1 = 1;
        T2 = 1;
    };
    
    for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        let ("T" + (i + 3)) = ("T" + i) + ("T" + (i + 1)) + ("T" + (i + 2))
        arr.push("T" + (i + 3));
    }
    
    return arr.find(e => e == ("T" + (n + 3));
```

**Final codebase:**

Thank you, Everyone, for the feedback.

1. I removed the "values" in the array because there are no keys & values arrays.
2. I removed the `.find()` method and added a simpler way to lookup `n` via `arr[n]`.

```
var tribonacci = function(n) {
  
    let arr = [0, 1, 1];
    
    for (i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
        let add = arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]
        arr.push(add);
    }
    
    return arr[n]
};
```

Comment: The array doesn't contain the strings, it just contains the integers.

Comment: `let arr = [
        T0 = 0,
        T1 = 1,
        T2 = 1
    ];` is odd syntax, it just creates an array `[0,1,1]` and creating 3 global variables, T0,T1 and T2 that are unconnected from the Array - I think you need a refresher course in Javascript syntax

Comment: you'll also see an error for the line `let ("T" + (i + 3)) =`

Comment: I just got it. He doesn't expect the array to contain the strings, he's expecting `c` to contain the value of `T2`.

Comment: You need to cover at least the basics of the language.  You are using nonexistent syntax.

Comment: May be defining an object is better in this case. Your array contains only the integers.

Comment: Objects use `{}` not `[]`.

Comment: You don't need `find()` with an object, you just use `arr[c]`

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks! I changed the object back into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this code will help (I may be out by one on the index, but you can fix that)

```js
var tribonacci = function(n) {
    let arr = [0, 1, 1];
    for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(arr.slice(-3).reduce((a,b) => a+b));
    }
    return arr[n];
};
console.log(tribonacci(1))
console.log(tribonacci(2))
console.log(tribonacci(3))
console.log(tribonacci(4))
console.log(tribonacci(7))
console.log(tribonacci(14))
```